# How to create a blank image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need help with Matlab code to answer the question below:

> In the spatial domain, apply Gaussian noise to a blank image (thereby creating a
> noise-only image). Show two image examples of medium and high levels of noise with an estimated variance (i.e. noise power) of 50 and 200.

Comment: @Angular_dev: you proposed a tag for this question relating to Angular Material. Can you explain why that would be a suitable tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 3-channel all-black RGB image:

```matlab
myimage = zeros(h,w,3, 'uint8');
```

Replace h and w with your height and width, of course.

And you can use whatever datatype you like to work with.